# how to read error.log file in cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to read error.log file.

```
function readerrorlog(){
      $file = new File('/tmp/error/error.log');
      $errorfile = $file->read(true, 'r');
}

$file returns array File Object
(
    [Folder] => Folder Object
        (
            [path] => 
            [sort] => 
            [mode] => 493
            [_messages:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_errors:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_directories:protected] => 
            [_files:protected] => 
        )

    [name] => error.log
    [info] => Array
        (
        )

    [handle] => 
    [lock] => 
    [path] => /error.log
)
```

and `$errorfile` is returning nothing

Answer (score 2):

By default error logs in CakePHP 3 are located in the logs folder.

```
YOURAPP
 /logs
 /plugins
 /src
 /...
```

Path to the logs directory [LOGS](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#core-definition-constants).

```
//$file = new File(LOGS.'error.log');

function readerrorlog(){
      $file = new File(LOGS.'error.log');
      $errorfile = $file->read();
      return $errorfile;
}
```

Comment: thanz @salines can you tell me how to get the last 50 lines from tat log file in cakephp?

Comment: explode("\n\n\n", $errorfile), then use array_reverse(), then use array_slice()